# Telephony system - calculating delayed message stats

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I'm having a bit of an issue with a question likely to be on an exam I'm taking soon. Details are-

> A messaging switching centre has three servers for passing messages to the network. If the servers are busy, the message passes into a queue for service on a first in first out basis. Message arrivals are Poissonian and server sesrvice times have a negative exponential distribution. During the busiest period, 400 messages arrive per minute. The average time taken to service a message is 5ms. Calculate the following:
>
> 1. The fraction of messages that experience a delay
> 2. The average delay for messages that experience a delay (in ms)
> 3. The fraction of messages that are delayed for longer than 8.33ms during the busy period.

My process for trying to answer the first question is to calculate the probabilities of *x* or more calls arriving in a second, based on the 400/60 = 6.66 messages/second arrival rate-

$P(0) = \mu^x e^{-\mu} / x! = {6.66^0*e^{-6.66}}/0! = 0.0013$

$P(1) = 0.085$

$P(2) = 0.0283$

$P(3) = 0.0628$

So ultimately-

$P(x >= 4) = 1 - P(0)-P(1)-P(2)-P(3) = 0.8991$

So the chance of 4 or more calls in a second is 89.91%, but I'm just mind-blanking on how to then calculate the chance of calls being placed in the queue based on the service time.

The answers provided to us are-

> 1. 0.444
> 2. 2.22
> 3. 0.01

Usually I'm pretty good at working backwards, but can't figure this one out. It's the method of this that I'm stuck with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.